# Binary Tree findHeight

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So I'm trying to add a findHeight method to my professors Binary Tree Class, and I'm having a bit of trouble.

```
  BTNode<T> findParent(BTNode<T> Root, BTNode<T> child)
  {
    if(!root)  
    {
        return Null;
    }

    if(Root.left* == child || Root.right* == child)
    {
        return Root;
    }
    else
    {
        //recursively checks left tree to see if child node is pointed to
        findParent(Root.left, child);

        //recursively checks right tree to see if child node is pointed to
        findParent(Root.right, child);
    }

  int findHeight(BTNode<T> thisNode)
  {
      if (Count.findParent(.root, thisNode) == null)    
      {
            return 0;
      }

      return findHeight(thisNode.findParent) + 1;
  }
```

My problem is that in the findHeight method, it calls the findParent() method, and I have to reference the root of the binary tree that the parameter thisNode comes from, and because this is just part of the class, I don't know how I am supposed to reference the root. The BT (binary tree) class has a function that returns the root of the tree, but since I have no Binary Tree to reference, I don't know what to do. Please Help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the `findHeight` function wouldn't "worry" about finding the root of the tree -- it just finds the height of the tree below whatever node it's passed. It usually looks something like this:

```
int findHeight(BTNode <T> *thiNode) { 
    if (thisNode == NULL)
        return 0;
    int left_height = findHeight(thisNode->left);
    int right_height = findHeight(thisNode->right);
    return 1 + max(left_height, right_height);
}
```

It's then up to the user to pass in the root of the tree whose height they want.

Comment: That makes sense. Kind of a follow up question to that, how would I go about finding the average height of every leaf in a tree? It would have worked with the way I did it (which was admittedly not the smartest way) if I had just iterated through the tree and found the height of each node. Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but your function seems to only work if you put the root in and find the height of whole tree, not find the heights of individual nodes.

Comment: @user1375501: At least at first glance, it seems like finding the average height of the tree would mostly involve adding 1 to the average of the heights of the two sub-trees, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it does. Thanks for all of the help :)